# I seem to have issues uploading images. i keep getting "Cannot use object of type App\Http\Controllers\PostsController as array. "

Tags: php, laravel, controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts/create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'caption' =>  'required',
            'image' =>  'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        ]);

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'caption' => $this['captions'],
            'image' => $imagePath,
        ]);

        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is this supposed to be: `$this['captions']` ?  `$this` is the current object (the controller) and you are trying to use it like an array

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: $this['captions'] was actually $this['caption']

I use Laravel 5.8.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is you are trying to access one of the inputs that were validated when creating the `Post` for the `User`:

```
// getting the inputs that were validated as an array
$data = $this->validate(...);

...

auth()->user()->posts()->create([
    'caption' => $data['caption'], // <------- accessing data array
    'image' => $imagePath,
]);
```

If your version of Laravel isn't returning the validated data from the `validate` call you can access the data from the `Request` itself:

```
'caption' => $request->input('caption')
```

Comment: This worked 
$data = $this->validate(...);
auth()->user()->posts()->create([
    'caption' => $data['caption'], // <------- accessing data array
    'image' => $imagePath,
]);


But it said “Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user “

Comment: @melvin so this fixed your issue from your question but what is the problem now? you are now talking about a completely different issue

Comment: already fixed it thanks